# os.tmpfile() doesn't work under windows?

Tags: python, windows

I'm trying to use generateDS under windows, which uses os.tmpfile. Unfortunately, os.tmpfile doesn't work for me:

```
(oneclickcos) C:\Users\Marcin\Documents\oneclickcos\xsd>python
Python 2.7.2 (default, Jun 12 2011, 14:24:46) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] on win
32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import os
>>> os.tmpfile()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied
>>>
```

I've got all my temp directories set with full control for everyone, so that shouldn't be the problem.

What could be causing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Run the script as administrator (right click on the script and select 'run as administrator'), the script lacks the permissions to execute os.tmpfile().

Edit:
As I see you're using the interpreter, simply run the interpreter as administrator. If you're accessing it though a terminal, running the terminal as administrator should be sufficient.

Comment: Thank you. Absolutely awful that this is the solution, but thank you very much - it works.

Answer (score 1):

As Griffin pointed out the problem is that the `os.tmpfile()` tries to create a file in the root directory. If you don't like to run the script as administrator you can use `os.tmpnam()` and handle the file yourself.

**Warning**: Use of tmpnam() is vulnerable to symlink attacks

Comment: The docs for `os.tmpnam()` (Python 2.7) specifically give the following warning: "This function probably shouldn’t be used on Windows, though: Microsoft’s implementation of tmpnam() always creates a name in the root directory of the current drive, and that’s generally a poor location for a temp file (depending on privileges, you may not even be able to open a file using this name)." However, the full symlink attack warning in the same docs is actually this: "**Warning** Use of tmpnam() is vulnerable to symlink attacks; consider using tmpfile() (section File Object Creation) instead." Er...